# How can I debug Django referer and CSRF checking?

Tags: django, security, debugging

**TL;DR**
I have found what seems to be a nasty bug in my Django site. The login form uses `{% csrf_token %}` and I also set `<meta name="referrer" content="same-origin">`. This login page works fine. However, trying to program a production site test, I noticed that if the CSRF token or the referer are not sent, the site logs this error, sends me an email but *still lets the test user in*. I can reproduce it with [python-requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) or with Chrome's [Servistate HTTP Editor & REST API client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/servistate-http-editor-re/mmdjghedkfbdhbjhmefbbgjaihmmhkeg) extension—but for some reason not with cURL command line tool, for which access seems to be blocked correctly. I am lost in how to debug it, and would really appreciate any hints.

**Full story**

I am quite new to Django, and have just started writing my first tests, and I fail to understand the situation I've discovered. My site has a login page, which makes use of CSRF token:

```
        <form id="login-form" method="post" action="/login">
            <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='2QXxnB5yTqOnEdsFVwgWfCbBam6JOvl49mnXk29mBgxVP1tvf7VWy0VvxzYtR3OT' />
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><input id="id_username" name="username" type="text"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input id="id_password" name="password" type="password"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr><td colspan="2">
                    <input type="submit" value="Enter" class="btn" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/home" />
                </td></tr>     
            </table>
        </form>
```

This form works fine. Without passing it I cannot access "secret" data, after login I can access it.

In my tests, I have created a `login()` function, used to test access to restricted data *on the deployed site*.

```
from django.test import TestCase
import requests

from rodichi import settings
PRFX = 'https://rodichi.net'

class ProductionServerTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.session = requests.Session()

    def login(self):
        url = PRFX + '/login'
        login_data = {'username': settings.TEST_USERNAME, 'password': settings.TEST_PASSWORD}
        headers = {'referer': url}
        r = self.session.post(url, data=login_data, headers=headers)
        self.assertEqual(r.status_code, 200)
        return r
```

Here starts the interesting part. Although the CSRF token is not passed in this function, it still works fine: my site tells me the test user is logged in (I get an email about it, and Axes logs every login event). At the same time, I do get an email about the CSRF verification error:

```
[Django] WARNING (EXTERNAL IP): Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /login
```

but the site still allows the user in!

Moreover, if I don't pass the referer with `POST`, I get another error: `[Django] WARNING (EXTERNAL IP): Forbidden (Referer checking failed - no Referer.): /login` and no CSRF error— but still the test user gets in.

What could be the reason? How could I debug it?

Here is the complete working example (with modified username and password):

```
import requests
PRFX = 'https://rodichi.net' 
TEST_PASSWORD = '51x6bJlH',
TEST_USERNAME = 'test'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    session = requests.Session()
    url = PRFX + '/login'
    login_data = {'username': TEST_USERNAME, 'password': TEST_PASSWORD}
    headers = {'referer': url}
    r = session.post(url, data=login_data, headers=headers)
    print(r.status_code)

    print("\nSecret-page\n")
    url = PRFX + '/people/50'
    r = session.get(url)
    print(r.status_code)
    print(r.content.decode('utf-8'))
```

It outputs the correct secret data with the last print. If login fails (e.g. invalid password), it will redirect to the login page. So the lack of CSRF doesn't disturb Django too much, though it does send me a notification email, as explained above. But why??

Comment: Are you using the Django test client? It [disables](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/#testing) the CSRF checks.

Comment: @Alasdair, good remark! I am inheriting from TestCase but only to get tests run by Django test command and get relevant reporting. This test is run on the production site, PRFX='https://rodichi.net'. I use it to make sure the production environment or database don't create buggy situations not caught in development. I don't think CSRF disabling applies in this case, does it?

Comment: I am also using python.requests.Session(). Not django. test.Client().